# Scrapy - get multiple urls from one link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Sample html:

```
<div id="foobar" foo="hello;world;bar;baz">blablabla</div>
```

I'm using `LinkExtractor` to get the attribute `foo`, namely the string `hello;world;bar;baz`. I wonder if it's possible to turn this string into multiple urls for the spider to follow, like `hello.com`, `world.com`, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

PS: the following might (or might not) be useful

1. `process_value` argument of [`LxmlLinkExtractor`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)
2. `process_links` argument of [`Rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)

Comment: "I'm using LinkExtractor to get the attribute foo, namely the string hello;world;bar;baz."  What is your current code for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, if you are using built-in `LinkExtractor`, *`process_value` callable has to return a single link* - it would fail [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/aa31811cfdc85eda07ddab25178d5003155523ec/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py#L62) if it's, in your case, a list of links.

You *would have to have a custom [Parser Link Extractor](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/aa31811cfdc85eda07ddab25178d5003155523ec/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py#L30)* which would support extracting multiple links per attribute, something like this (not tested):

```
class MyParserLinkExtractor(LxmlParserLinkExtractor):
    def _extract_links(self, selector, response_url, response_encoding, base_url):
        links = []
        # hacky way to get the underlying lxml parsed document
        for el, attr, attr_val in self._iter_links(selector.root):
            # pseudo lxml.html.HtmlElement.make_links_absolute(base_url)
            try:
                attr_val = urljoin(base_url, attr_val)
            except ValueError:
                continue # skipping bogus links
            else:
                url = self.process_attr(attr_val)
                if url is None:
                    continue
            if isinstance(url, unicode):
                url = url.encode(response_encoding)

            # url here is a list
            for item in url:
                url = urljoin(response_url, item)
                link = Link(item, _collect_string_content(el) or u'',
                            nofollow=rel_has_nofollow(el.get('rel')))
                links.append(link)

        return unique_list(links, key=lambda link: link.url) \
                if self.unique else links
```

Then, based on it, define your actual Link Extractor:

```
class MyLinkExtractor(LxmlLinkExtractor):
    def __init__(self, allow=(), deny=(), allow_domains=(), deny_domains=(), restrict_xpaths=(),
                 tags=('a', 'area'), attrs=('href',), canonicalize=True,
                 unique=True, process_value=None, deny_extensions=None, restrict_css=()):
        tags, attrs = set(arg_to_iter(tags)), set(arg_to_iter(attrs))
        tag_func = lambda x: x in tags
        attr_func = lambda x: x in attrs
        lx = MyParserLinkExtractor(tag=tag_func, attr=attr_func,
            unique=unique, process=process_value)

        super(LxmlLinkExtractor, self).__init__(lx, allow=allow, deny=deny,
            allow_domains=allow_domains, deny_domains=deny_domains,
            restrict_xpaths=restrict_xpaths, restrict_css=restrict_css,
            canonicalize=canonicalize, deny_extensions=deny_extensions)
```

You would then need to have `tags`, `attrs` and `process_value` defined:

```
MyLinkExtractor(tags=["div"], attrs=["foo"], process_value=extract_links)
```

where `extract_links` is defined as:

```
def extract_links(value):
    return ["https://{}.com".format(part) for part in value.split(";")]
```

Comment: I had about 2 minutes left on writing a custom LinkExtractor, but you beat me to it.  This is the answer I'd recommend.  Depending on what this is being used for, it may be a better option to not use a LinkExtractor, and instead use a Selector to grab the text from the `foo` attr of the div and manually generate new `Request`s for the url.  Obviously, this won't work if your expecting a `Link` item to be returned, though (such as rules).

Comment: @Rejected I agree that having a selector extracting the attributes and manually yielding the Requests would probably look cleaner but it would probably miss flexibility and reusability. The current approach looks too complicated (or may be I'm just overcomplicating it with all the link extractor -> parser link extractor logic)..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this will work for u

```
 def url_break(value):
    for url in value.split(';'):
        yield url

  class MyParserLinkExtractor(CrawlSpider):
        rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(, restrict_xpaths=YOUR_XPATH_LIST, process_value=url_break)),]
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.